# std::thread detect main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

is thre any relieable way in c++11 to detect if the current thread is the main thread? Or would I have to manually save the main threads thread id with `std::this_thread::get_id()` and then have a routine like this:

```
bool isMainThread()
{
    return theMainThreadIdISavedOnProgramStart == std::this_thread::get_id();
}
```

Is there a common way to do this? Would the above solution work?

Thanks

Comment: You could also set a flag in thread-local storage, but I am not sure if TLS is broadly available at this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you mean by main thread? If you mean, the thread which executes `main()`, then there is no way you can know if a thread is a main thread or not. You've to save its ID and later on you can use the *saved* ID to know if a current thread is a main thread or not, by comparing its ID with the saved ID (as you guessed in your question).

To explain it a bit more, threads do not have hierarchy, there is no parent thread, no child thread even if one thread creates the other threads. The OS doesn't remember which threads created by which thread. Therefore, all threads are same to the OS, and to your program. So you cannot infer a `main` thread, by detecting if the current thread is the parent of all other threads in your application.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I indeed ment the thread executing main()! I will manually save the id then! Thank you!

Comment: Very correct answer. As a sidenote and depending on the platform, on POSIX platforms running FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Mac OS X or iOS, there is a function in pthread.h - int pthread_main_np(void); This returns non-zero if the thread is the main thread. If you have spawned a thread using std::thread, this underlying function will work correctly. Note the "np" at the end of the function means "non-portable", so still Nawaz has the best platform-independent answer.